# Error: No such partition when trying to boot Windows

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation, grubrescue

I get the error `no such partition, entering grub rescue`, after restarting my computer.

I have a pen drive with an Ubuntu ISO image, so I booted from it. On opening the file manger there, I found that the files I had in my Windows were all there in the same partition (only the C drive).

How can I boot into my existing Windows?

Since Windows was pre-installed in my laptop, I do not have the Windows DVD.

Comment: UEFI or BIOS, or What version of Windows? You are supposed to make your own Windows recovery and Windows repair CD/DVD/Flash depending on version. Plus backups are important. Post this: `sudo parted -l` That will tell us about install. If UEFI you should be able to just go into UEFI & boot Windows. If BIOS: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestoreUbuntu/XP/Vista/7Bootloader

Comment: Windows 7, the sudo parted-1 throws an error  command not found

Comment: I ran the testdisk, it shows no sectors were bad and that the recovery was located in the fatt32 partition. I couldn't understand how to proceed from there.

Comment: The command is to be run from the terminal in the Ubuntu live installer in live mode. I do not know any Windows commands anymore.

Comment: yes, i ran it in the ubuntu terminal, the mode i used was try ubuntu. Is that what you mean,and when using the sudo parted -l i get this information

Comment: $ sudo parted -l
Model: ATA ST9320325AS (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 320GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
 1      32.8kB  21.0GB  21.0GB  primary  fat32        boot, lba
 2      21.0GB  268GB   247GB   primary  ntfs
 3      268GB   320GB   52.4GB  primary  ntfs


Model: Kingston DataTraveler G3 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 3870MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
 1      32.3kB  3869MB  3869MB  primary  fat32        boot

Comment: Windows only boots from MBR(msdos) with BIOS. You do show a FAT32 boot partition, which is not correct. Windows needs a NTFS partitition with boot flag & its boot files. Only UEFI uses boot flag on FAT32, but then drive would have to be gpt partitioned. You show no Linux partitions. Use Boot-Repair to restore Windows boot loader. Either change (not reformat) with Disks sda1 from FAT32 to NTFS or move boot flag to sda2. Then Windows should boot. You have used 3 or the 4 primary partitions, so you can create one extended partition and inside it logical partitions for Ubuntu.

Comment: Hi, please correct me if I am wrong. So I need to use gparted and probably select /dev/sda2 and then click on partitions, and then go to manage flags and check the boot option, and at the same time, uncheck the boot option for FAT32, is this how it needs to be done?

Comment: Anyway, I installed lilo, lost all my software installed on windows 7, but atleast got my windows back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Boot with the USB drive for Ubuntu installation
2. Select the option `Try Ubuntu without installing`.
3. Open the file manager, and if you see that all files which were there in your Windows are intact, then immediately take a backup of all those folders (if you cannot manage to get a lot of space, go for using only important files) Also check for files in the user's folder and copy them to another USB or external hard drive, not the USB which you are booting from which will not retain any data.
4. Use [boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestoreUbuntu/XP/Vista/7Bootloader) and Testdisk as [mentioned](https://askubuntu.com/questions/647223/error-no-such-partition-when-trying-to-boot-windows#comment928470_647223) above in the comments and reboot your system.
5. If the above fails, install lilo and reboot your system.

Voila! You get your computer in a brand new state, but use the hard drive to install software. And please feel free to correct me if anywhere I have been wrong in this process; there are really good people out there who can solve your problem better than me.

P.S. Backup is really important.